# How to create a file in resource/view directory Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0 and I am trying to create a view if is does not exits like so

```
if (view()->exists($moduleName.$getCategoryNameToLowerCase))
    {
        //if exist return the view
         return view($moduleName.$getCategoryNameToLowerCase);
    }
    else{
         //else create a view and return it;
         fopen( app_path('../resources/','views/'.$moduleName .'.'. $getCategoryNameToLowerCase . '.blade.php' ), 'w');
         return view($moduleName.$getCategoryNameToLowerCase);
    }
```

But I dont know why I am still not able to go one folder backwards to reach the resource folder it still says this

```
fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\foobar\app/../resources/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: i think you should make it an absolute path, it's not parsing the `../`

Comment: How do I do it? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use `app_path`, you can use `base_path` instead

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-base-path